# Changing expression provided to ngShow attribute using controller

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-show and ng-hide to display/hide content. I would like to change the showme status from true to false within the controller. But when I use the code below, it doesn't work. I'm using the Controller As syntax. Any suggestions on how to get this working right?

HTML:

```
<h1 ng-show="showme">Confirm Order</h1>

<h4 ng-hide="showme">Contact Information</h4>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller('ContactFormCtrl',
   function ($http, serviceF, $scope) {
     var contactForm = this;

     $scope.$watch(serviceF.get, function(valid)

     {    
       if (valid === 'yes') {
         contactForm.showme=true;   
       } 
      else 
     {
         contactForm.showme=false;
       }
     });
});
```

Service:

```
.service('serviceF', function() {

   var valid = 'true';
   return {
      get: function () {
       return valid;
    },
      set: function (value) {
      valid = value;
    }
  };
```

UI Router:

```
.state('payment', {
   url: '/payment',
    views: {

  // . . . 
   'top': {
    templateUrl: 'views/clientinfo.html',
    controller: 'ContactFormCtrl as contactForm'

  // . . . 
    }
})
```

Comment: `$scope.$watch(serviceF.get` what are you doing there? "--> it doesn't work" Are you seeing infinite digest error? How is this code related to what you say you are trying to do.

Comment: @PSL I'm trying to watch a value set by another controller and display/hide content based on that value. When I console.log() the value, it seems to work OK. I've added the service in case that helps.

Comment: You are not using controllerAs properly though. Checkout docs. for ex: `ng-controller="ContactFormCtrl as vm"` and `ng-show="vm.showme"` etc

Comment: @PSL In UI Router, I have `controller: 'ContactFormCtrl as contactForm'`. Should I change it to `ContactFormCtrl as vm` and then change `ng-show="showme"` to `ng-show="vm.showme"`?

Comment: if you have that then just `contactForm.showme` `as` stands for `alias`, it can be anything. i just used `vm` as an exmaple

Comment: @PSL Thanks. I changed `ng-show="showme"` to `ng-show="contactForm.showme"` but still no luck.

Comment: Might be your angular version then. it is not supported `lt 1.3`

Comment: @PSL Using 1.4. But was having same problem in 1.3.

Comment: You must be doing some mistake somewhere. Either you need to provide us a demo replicating the issue or you can probably debug yourself. :( Also did you check if it takes expression that way or in another property controllerAs in the router settings. [Check out docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#controllers)

Comment: @PSL Figured out my mistake (sloppy copy/paste job). Your solution above worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but the Controller As syntax goes this way in HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="ContactFormCtrl as contactForm">
   <h1 ng-show="contactForm.showme">Confirm Order</h1>
   <h1 ng-show="contactForm.showme">Confirm Order</h1>
</div>
```

*Note the 'as contactForm' thingy passed in the ng-controller directive*

Now you know that `showme` is actually a property of `contactForm` which is essentially an "alias" of the `ContactFormCtrl` controller

From there, whenever the `showme` property changes in the controller, the view will behave accordingly.

```
// In your controller
var contactForm = this; // aliasing this
contactForm.showme = true; //or false
```

**UPDATE:**
Since you're using ui-router, you should be good without ng-controller in your view. I'm noticing you are not passing `$scope` to your controller, that could be a reason why `$scope.$watch` isn't working, thus not updating the view.

```
.controller('ContactFormCtrl', function ($scope, $http, serviceF) {
    var contactForm = this;

    $scope.$watch(serviceF.get, function(valid) {    
      if (valid === 'yes') {
        contactForm.showme = true;   
      }else{
        contactForm.showme = false;
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: I'm using UI Router for the Controller As syntax.

Comment: The problem was that I didn't put `contactForm` before `showme` in the HTML.

Comment: Yes. You could test initially with `$scope.showme`, and use `ng-show="showme"` and see if that worked. Then gradually add up and find the issue.